# How can I use Ubuntu 18.04 on double screen?

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am currently on my laptop in dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04.
It has an HDMI output that I can use on Windows to connect a second monitor.

But on my Ubuntu boot, the HDMI output doesn't seem to be recognized and in the settings, I can't add another screen.

[Settings Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8q3V.png)

Is there someone who knows what's the problem and how I can solve it ?

Thanks

EDIT :

1)
[sudo lshw -c video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOcln.png)

```
*-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: mémoire:a3000000-a3ffffff mémoire:90000000-9fffffff mémoire:a0000000-a1ffffff portE/S:4000(taille=128) mémoire:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:139 mémoire:a2000000-a2ffffff mémoire:b0000000-bfffffff portE/S:5000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

2)
[lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqLcu.png)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1262]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [10de:1c8c] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [1025:1263]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
```

3)
[xrandr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xznnw.png)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

4)
[pulseaudio --check -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIr1O.png)

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon running as PID 1628
```

5) 
mokutil --sb-state

```
SecureBoot enabled
```

6)
test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"

```
efi
```

7)
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

```
x11
```

8)
dkms status

```
nvidia, 430.09, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
```

7)
lsmod | grep nvidia

```
//Nothing found
```

8)
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001025sd00001263bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `sudo lshw -c video`  2. `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"` 3. `xrandr` and 4. `pulseaudio --check -v`. Thanks.

Comment: You have a Nvidia but you didn't install drivers. That's the problem.

Comment: Done @Marmayogi

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia This is a NVIDIA driver or I am wrong ?
https://imgur.com/w0MkntJ

If not, how can I see what driver is installed ?

Comment: A 1050ti needs driver version 418 or newer which isn't available in the 18.04 repositories. You need to add the graphics drivers PPA and then install a correct version. Older versions do not support the card and that's the same as not having it installed.

Comment: I followed this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Is this good ? : https://imgur.com/BYlUD4N

Do I need to connect another screen to see the settings saying I can add another monitor? because nothing changes on this window : https://imgur.com/XWDNMYe

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"` 3. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` 4. `dkms status` 5. `lsmod | grep nvidia` and 6. `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`. Also Restart your computer and reach `BIOS Setup screen` by pressing `del` key. Then `disable` secured boot. Also please upgrade Motherboard BIOS `firmware` to the latest version.

Comment: Done @Marmayogi.
I have a problem with secure boot because I don't have the password but I didn't configure it...

Comment: Command `dkms status` says that you have latest `Nividia 430` installed in the system but this driver is not used. You must `disable` secured boot in order for Nvidia to function.  Did you attempt to disable? Was there any problem? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: There are ways to [Reset BIOS password](https://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS). You may refer another tutorial [3 Ways to Remove or Reset BIOS Password If Forgotten](https://www.tunesbro.com/reset-bios-rassword.html)

Comment: I am really busy these days, so I will try it as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: Hello, I disabled the secure boot, try reinstalling the nvidia 430 driver (it tells me to choose a password and use it on reboot, which I did) BUT I still don't have an option on the Linux settings screen to add an ohter screen (Screen 1) when the driver seems to work (I have all the information about the card in the NVIDIA X Server Settings application: its current temperature, etc) (Screen 2) ||||||| (Screen 1 : https://i.imgur.com/4aTi4c6.png) (Screen 2 : https://i.imgur.com/9hNwpKN.png). Do you know why ?